# Change SQL to NoSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, mongodb

I am new to NoSQL database and I have this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalIndex, SUM(Expense)AS Outflow, SUM(Income) AS Inflow, DATE_FORMAT(Date, '%b, %Y') AS Month
FROM store
GROUP BY month, year(Date)
ORDER BY Date
```

But I don't know where to start, I have been trying to use this [website](http://www.querymongo.com/) but it is not helping too much.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: "Convert my code" questions are typically not helpful, and largely due to the different ways different technologies work and indeed "how you should be storing things differently" between them. Your real first stop should be [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) rather than any external ( and outdated, as `group()` is now deprecated ) resource. And then presenting an actual attempt and small data sample if you still have problems understanding. Personal knowledge is better than tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mongodb [aggregate framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) to build the query.

Assuming your database table "store" has at least three fields (Expense, Income and Date), something like this could work (not tested):

```
db.store.aggregate(
   [
     { $project : { expense: 1, income: 1, date:1, month: { $month: "$date" }, year: { $year: "$date"} } },
     { $group : { _id : {month: '$month',year:'$year'}, totalIndex: { $count: 1 }, outflow: { $sum: "$expense" }, inflow: { $sum: "$income" } } },
     { $sort : { date : 1 } },
     { $project : { totalIndex: 1, outflow: 1, inflow:1, month:  { "$concat" : [ "$month",  ", ", "$year" ] } } }
   ]
)
```

Your documents go through a pipeline which consists of several stages:

1. Project the fields you want to use for computing the group-by
2. Doing the actual group-by the month and year extracted from the Date column, defining the count and sums of different columns
3. Sort by date ascending
4. Project the output in such a way that only the desired result is left, including the custom month notation

Comment: That actually would not be the translation. After the `$group` there is no such property visible in the document as `date`, of which you propose to `$sort` on. That's how a "pipeline" works. Where the only "input" available to a given stage is the "output" of the stage that precedes it. It's also pretty horrible practice to `$project` before a `$group` if you understand that pipeline concept and what is actually happening.

Comment: You are right Neil, I wanted to give OP a head start, I'll correct my answer in a bit.

Comment: @AkimanaAjoullyJeand'Amour, no problem. If my answer helped you, you could accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.